# 404 error while trying to push data to Grafana Cloud Prometheus

Tags: python-3.x, prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to write a simple code which will send some of in-app metrics to Grafana Cloud. I'm using Python3.8 with prometheus_client library. My app shouldn't be **scraped**, so I don't deploy a local Prometheus instance and using prometheus_client.push_to_gateway() to send data to Grafana's Prometheus directly. The problem is in "HTTP 404 Not Found" error which I get every time I'm trying to push data. What could be the problem here?

The code:

```
from prometheus_client import CollectorRegistry, Gauge, push_to_gateway
from prometheus_client.exposition import basic_auth_handler


if __name__ == '__main__':
    registry = CollectorRegistry()
    def my_auth_handler(url, method, timeout, headers, data):
        username = <MyUsername>
        password = <MyGrafanaCloudKey>
        return basic_auth_handler(url, method, timeout, headers, data, username, password)

    g = Gauge('job_last_success_unixtime', 'Last time a batch job successfully finished', registry=registry)
    g.set_to_current_time()

    push_to_gateway('https://prometheus-us-central1.grafana.net/api/prom/push',
                    job='TestJob',
                    registry=registry,
                    handler=my_auth_handler)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/y.sosunov/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/scratches/prometheus2grafana.py", line 15, in <module>
    push_to_gateway('https://prometheus-us-central1.grafana.net/api/prom/push',
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/prometheus_client/exposition.py", line 286, in push_to_gateway
    _use_gateway('PUT', gateway, job, registry, grouping_key, timeout, handler)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/prometheus_client/exposition.py", line 359, in _use_gateway
    handler(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/prometheus_client/exposition.py", line 240, in handle
    default_handler(url, method, timeout, headers, data)()
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/prometheus_client/exposition.py", line 218, in handle
    resp = build_opener(HTTPHandler).open(request, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Well, I've used TimeScaleDb for my needs, but the issue with Cloud Prometheus is still unresolved